# A stationary action principle for an oscillator with position-dependent damping

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, friction, variational-principle, oscillators, dissipation

> I wonder if the equation of motion of an oscillator with (position-dependent) damping
> \begin{equation*}
>   \ddot{x}+\gamma(x)\dot{x}+\omega_{0}^{2}x=0 \tag{1}
> \end{equation*}
> can be derived directly from a [stationary action principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary-action_principle)?

Clearly, if $\gamma$ does not depend on the position, then the time-dependent damped Lagrangian $$\mathcal{L}(x,\dot{x},t)=e^{\gamma t}(\dot{x}^{2}-\omega_{0}^{2}x^{2})/2\tag{2}$$ would do the job.

Concerning a non-variational Lagrangian formulation, the above equation (1) can be derived by introducing the [Rayleigh dissipation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_dissipation_function)
$$Q(x,\dot{x})=-\frac{\partial\mathcal{F}}{\partial\dot{x}},\tag{3}$$
where
$$\mathcal{F}(x,\dot{x})=\frac{1}{2}\gamma(x)\dot{x}^{2}.\tag{4}$$
However, does there exist a stationary action principle for equation (1)?

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: *Yes,* a variational formulation/stationary action principle exists locally if the variable $x$ is 1-dimensional (rather than multi-dimensional).

One can rewrite any second-order [ODE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation) (such as OP's eom) as 2 coupled first-order OPEs $$ \dot{x}~=~f(x,y), \qquad   \dot{y}~=~g(x,y).\tag{A}$$
More generally, a variational formulation exists locally for any system of the form (A).

*Sketched existence proof:*

1. It is explained in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/432672/2451) that there exists locally a Hamiltonian formulation
   $$   \dot{x}~=~\{x,H\}, \qquad   \dot{y}~=~\{y,H\}\tag{B}$$
   of the system (A).
2. A Poisson structure in 2 dimensions is fully determined by a single function
   $$B(x,y)~:=~\{x,y\}.\tag{C}$$
3. The corresponding symplectic 2-form
   $$\omega~=~\frac{1}{B}\mathrm{d}y\wedge \mathrm{d}x~=~\mathrm{d}\theta\tag{D}$$ is locally [exact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential), where $$\theta~=~a(x,y)~\mathrm{d}x+b(x,y)~\mathrm{d}y\tag{E}$$
   is a symplectic potential 1-form.
4. The Hamilton's equations (B) are the [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) of the following Hamiltonian Lagrangian:
   $$L_H~:=~a\dot{x}+b\dot{y}-H . \tag{F}$$
5. The corresponding action is
   $$ S_H~=~\int \! dt~L_H. \tag{G}$$
   $\Box$

Note that the Lagrangian (F) does not depend explicitly on time unlike eq. (2).