# Experimentally relevant example of a time dependent Lagrangian

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, time

Usually in a classical mechanics class, the Lagrangians are time independent and hence have a conserved energy.  Occasionally, a teacher writes down a contrived example with a simple time dependence but usually without trying very hard (if at all) to connect the example to the physical world we live in.  I was wondering if someone knows a good physically relevant example of a time dependent Lagrangian.  I would be especially interested in an example which is useful for modeling a familiar physical phenomenon.

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/311168/

Comment: 1. Take e.g. any Lagrangian and add an external source term. 2. E.g. consider the Lagrangian for a point charge in a time-dependent E&M background field.

Comment: Exercise 14 from chapter 2 of Goldstein feels contrived to me.  Thank you for the example of the time-dependent E&M background field.